# Grassmannian as a smooth projective variety

Tags: algebraic-geometry, grassmannian

I have to prove that the Grassmannian is a smooth projective variety.

I was able to show that it is a projective variety using this script: [https://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Hudec.pdf](https://www.math.uchicago.edu/%7Emay/VIGRE/VIGRE2007/REUPapers/FINALFULL/Hudec.pdf), but I have trouble with the smooth part and I only find proofs showing that the Grassmannian is a smooth manifold. I am terrible in Algebraic Geometry, but I think I cannot use these proofs since the Grassmanian has the Zarisky topology as a variety and there it is not Hausdorf. Is there an easy proof to show that the Grassmannian is also a smooth variety?

Comment: It depends of course on what these proofs look like. If they really show that the Grassmannian is a submanifold of that projective space, with a submanifold chart made with algebraic local coordinates – then it should be good with some “GAGA-like abstract nonsense”, at least over the complex/real numbers (then by descent over $\mathbb{Q}$, then by base change in characteristic zero). But this doesn’t work in finite characteristic – although perhaps the argument can still be mimicked (if the local coordinates keep making sense in this field and the Jacobian criterion still holds).

Comment: I did not show that the Grassmannian is a submanifold of that projective space, I just used an argument like in the answer of that question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/492846/show-the-grassmannian-is-a-smooth-manifold-using-dummy-definition-of-smooth-man.

Comment: The main issue I’m seeing is that this construction of the Grassmannian is very dependent on the fact that $\mathbb{R}$ is your base field.